# Show different fragments of a slide on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, reveal.js

I'm trying to use webslides - https://github.com/webslides/WebSlides. I'm not a coder, but this looks awesome and I want to try and use it. I have a question on a functionality that might exist, but I might not see it.
I'm looking to how to show different parts/fragments of a slide one after the other. For example, on your demo site ,the slides from 15 to 23 show different text fragments positioned in different parts of the slide, but the only one fragment at a time is visible. What if I want to show all these fragments one by one (on arrow click) so in the end I see all of them on the same slide? It's like revealing individual parts of a slide one step at a time. I think reveal.js calls it fragmented slide, but webslides is easier to use, so if you could explain me how I can recreate this functionality, it'd be great.

I tried this to put two similar divs in the same section, but i still shows both at the same time and not one after the other.

```
<section class="slide-top">
          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="content-left">
              <h4>1/9 left top</h4>
              <p>Put content wherever you want. Have less. Do more</p>
              <p><code>.slide-top and .content-left</code></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="content-right">
              <h4>1/9 right top</h4>
              <p>Put content wherever you want. Have less. Do more</p>
              <p><code>.slide-top and .content-right</code></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- .end .wrap -->
        </section>
```

This code gives me two fragments appearing at the same time

[image]

but I want one after the other.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know WebSlides, looks very nice. You refer to this demo page, I assume: https://webslides.tv/demos/components#slide=15

This examples part is built like this:

```
<section class="slide-top">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-left">
      <h3>1/9 left top</h3>
      <p>Put content wherever you want. Have less. Do more. Create beautiful solutions.</p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-left</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
</section>
<section class="slide-top">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-center">
      <h3>2/9 center top</h3>
      <p>Your story needs to be clear. A great lasting story is about everyone or it will not last. </p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-center</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
</section>
<section class="slide-top">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-right">
      <h3>3/9 right top</h3>
      <p>Your story needs to be short. Select words carefully, each one must convey a meaning.</p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-right</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
</section>
```

As stated here, each `<section>` is an individual slide, so the example above shows different slides.

Basically you have given the answer, it is possible in https://revealjs.com/ and is called *Fragments* (https://revealjs.com/#/fragments). But WebSlides is designed to keep it simple.

I don't know if there is a built-in way to do what you want, but the quick and dirty solution is copy-paste: You use the first element on the first slide, the first and the second element on the second slide, the first and the second and the third element on the third slide. So you would have to edit the fragments **n** times. This is very bad duplication and to avoid this you have to do some programming - or use *reveal.js*. 
But, it works to a certain extent:

```
<section class="slide-top">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-left">
      <h3>1/9 left top</h3>
      <p>Put content wherever you want. Have less. Do more. Create beautiful solutions.</p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-left</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
</section>
<section class="slide-top">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-left">
      <h3>1/9 left top</h3>
      <p>Put content wherever you want. Have less. Do more. Create beautiful solutions.</p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-left</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-center">
      <h3>2/9 center top</h3>
      <p>Your story needs to be clear. A great lasting story is about everyone or it will not last. </p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-center</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
</section>
<section class="slide-top">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-left">
      <h3>1/9 left top</h3>
      <p>Put content wherever you want. Have less. Do more. Create beautiful solutions.</p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-left</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-center">
      <h3>2/9 center top</h3>
      <p>Your story needs to be clear. A great lasting story is about everyone or it will not last. </p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-center</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content-right">
      <h3>3/9 right top</h3>
      <p>Your story needs to be short. Select words carefully, each one must convey a meaning.</p>
      <p><code>.slide-top and .content-right</code></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .end .wrap -->
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll need to dig a bit deeper into it.

Comment: I try this, now the only 'bad thing' is that there is a transition from one slide to another, and you'll have to show all parts on every slide, hiding them with visibility otherwise you have trouble with alignment too